# How would I tell postgres to scan and stop if any Null values are detected in column x?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a few million rows. What query could I use to scan and see if any of them have null values for column X and then stop when the null value is detected in postgresql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are thinking procedurally rather than relationally: you will not "scan" for anything; the DBMS might scan the data internally, but that is for it to optimise.

Re-phrased in terms of the result you want, the question becomes something more like this: "What is the most efficient way of checking if there is at least one NULL in a column?"

To that question, my answer would be this:

```
SELECT true AS null_detected FROM some_table WHERE column_x IS NULL LIMIT 1;
```

This will return a single row with `true` in if there is at least one `NULL` in the column, or no rows if there are no `NULL`s at all.  You could also use this, but I suspect Postgres will be smart enough to perform roughly the same "query plan" in both cases:

```
SELECT true AS null_detected WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM some_table WHERE column_x IS NULL);
```

Either way, the biggest performance factor will be whether there is an index on `column_x`; without it, Postgres will have to scan every row of the table as you envisioned. With an index, though, it should be able to look at the index and come up with an answer more-or-less instantly.

Comment: A surprising number of SQL problems come down to "say exactly what you mean" rather than trying to tell the database how to find what you want. This seems to be one of the biggest problems people have with relational databases.

Comment: Good answer. Just to add that with some other RDBMS's nulls are not included in some index types by default, so some special measures might have to be taken.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I did wonder about that actually, but didn't know the details so decided not to mention it. "Be aware of the possibility" is good advice though.